# SharePoint Copy Date with Calculated field

Tags: sharepoint

Basically, we are trying to compare our task original start and end dates. This is to get some idea how often we push work out and by how much. Basic metrics.

On the input form to the sharepoint list we have:
2 inputs the user selects as start and end dates (as dateTime) called Start Date and End Date
and
2 columns that are hidden which we'd like to set as those original intended dates called duplicate Start and duplicate End (as dateTime as well).

The problem: For the hidden duplicate date columns, we are trying to use a calculated field such as =[Start Date], however we get an error which isn't very descriptive: "The formula contains reference(s) to field(s)."

We've tried wrapping in =TEXT([Start Date]), we've tried using =DATE(Year([Start Date]), Month[Start Date]... etc but all variations don't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

*I should mention I don't have access to the sharepoint environment as I'm not an administrator or anything so I can't add scripts, or use power automate etc.

Comment: Are you creating the calculated columns for duplicate date columns? Can you add screenshot to your question where you are adding this formula? Also, make sure you are using correct display names of original date columns in the formula.